# PyInstaller - PyInstaller does not compile my imported scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a Python script, which receives data from another script and uses it on a Kivy screen, but PyInstaller apparently is not finding another script that is imported at the beginning of my main file.

After starting .exe Kivy starts normally, looking at the console window, but after that it quickly opens the Kivy window and closes.

The main file is inside the "src" folder.

Would anyone know how I can get PyInstaller to find and compile my scripts?

File that I'm trying to compile (Main.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
# from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from src.Controller.ModuloController import ModuloController
import multiprocessing
from screeninfo import get_monitors
import kivy.resources
import sys
import os


class Float(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Float, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.modulos = ModuloController.listar()
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',
                             padding=[20, 20],
                             spacing=20)
        self.box.grid = Grid(self.modulos)
        self.add_widget(self.box)
        self.box.add_widget(self.box.grid)


class Grid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self,
                 modulos,
                 **kwargs):
        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.rows = 2
        self.cols = 2
        self.spacing = 20
        for modulo in modulos:
            if modulo.nome == 'Caixa':
                self.add_widget(Button(text=modulo.nome,
                                       on_press=self.abrir_caixa,
                                       font_size=36,
                                       background_normal='',
                                       background_color=[0/255.0,
                                                         75/255.0,
                                                         198/255.0,
                                                         1]))
            elif modulo.nome == 'Retaguarda':
                self.add_widget(Button(text=modulo.nome,
                                       on_press=self.abrir_retaguarda,
                                       font_size=36,
                                       background_normal='',
                                       background_color=[0/255.0,
                                                         75/255.0,
                                                         198/255.0,
                                                         1]))

    def abrir_caixa(self, t):
        m = multiprocessing.Process(target=ModuloController().iniciar,
                                    args=('Caixa',))
        m.start()

    def abrir_retaguarda(self, t):
        m = multiprocessing.Process(target=ModuloController().iniciar,
                                    args=('Retaguarda',))
        m.start()


class ACApp(App):

    def build(self):
        # Config.set('graphics', 'width', str(get_monitors()[0].width - 7))
        # Config.set('graphics', 'height', str(get_monitors()[0].height - 30))
        # Config.set('graphics', 'top', 30)
        # Config.set('graphics', 'left', 7)
        # Config.write()
        Window.size = [900, 450]
        Window.top = int(get_monitors()[0].height // 2 - Window.size[1] // 2)
        Window.left = int(get_monitors()[0].width // 2 - Window.size[0] // 2)
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        return Float()


class AcInterface(object):

    def iniciar(self):
        ACApp().run()


def resourcePath():
    '''Returns path containing content - either locally or in pyinstaller tmp file'''
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS)

    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    kivy.resources.resource_add_path(resourcePath())  # add this line
    # main = multiprocessing.Process(target=AcInterface().iniciar)
    # main.start()
    ACApp().run()
```

I modified the .spec generated by PyInstaller and recompile:

```
    # -*- mode: python -*-

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
import multiprocessing
from screeninfo import get_monitors
import kivy.resources
import sys
import os
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import get_deps_minimal, get_deps_all, hookspath, runtime_hooks


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['JC_AC_App.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\sony\\Downloads\\Scripts-Python\\AC\\src',
             'C:\\Users\\sony\\Downloads\\Scripts-Python\\AC\\src\\Controller'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hookspath=hookspath(),
             runtime_hooks=runtime_hooks(),
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False,
             **get_deps_all())
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='JC_AC_App',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='JC_AC_App')
```

I tried to put the "from src.Controller.ModuloController import ModuloController" in the .spec, however it results in the following error:

```
965 WARNING: stderr:   File "<string>", line 7, in <module> ImportError: No module named src.Controller.ModuloController
967 WARNING: stderr: ImportError: No module named src.Controller.ModuloController
```

I have already warned of errors related to Kivy compilation and multiprocessing in Windows.

Comment: Can you try adding path to you base src dir, such as
pathex=['C:\\Users\\sony\\Downloads\\Scripts-Python\\AC\\src', ...]

Comment: This is how it's in the .spec file that I recompiled

Comment: Did you do a onefile build or a normal one, if its normal build, check the dist folder for your src lib, by the books it you include your base dir (in which your script is there) and external dir paths to pathex it should work.

Comment: How are you determining that `Pyinstaller` is not finding the imported script? Are you getting any error messages when you run the `.exe`?

Comment: I believe that your `.spec` file will create a `one folder` app, so that your `.exe` must be executed in that folder, and cannot be copied somewhere else and executed.

Comment: @NishantPatel I used the normal build, however, the src directory is not created within the dist. I tried to use Nuitka and the src directory was also not found.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I removed the import and all calls to ModuloController from the script and this caused the Kivy interface to open and enter mainloop. I'm running .exe in the folder, don't worry.

Comment: Are there non `.py` files in your `ModuloController` that are needed? (`.txt` files, images, etc.)

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yes, it has an import in my ModuloController file, but it is from another .py

Comment: `Pyinstaller` should be able to follow any imports of `.py` files, but any other non-py files that those Python files access may not be automatically included. Any such files (images, icons, `.kv` files, text files, etc.)  will need to be specified using the `datas` list in your `.spec` file.

Comment: I found the problem, I just needed to add the project root and all subfolders from `src` to pathex

Comment: Thanks for help and attention

Comment: @JohnAnderson It took a while, but I'm getting the PyInstaller tricks. Thank you.

Comment: One other comment. I don't think you need all those import statements in your `.spec` file. The `kivy.deps` and the `kivy.tools` lines are needed, but I believe the rest can be removed.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Probably not really. I'll try it later. Thanks for the tip.